# How to call Firebase Cloud Function that uses ExpressJS with cloud_functions

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function setup with ExpressJS which I would like to call call from my app.

I could of course just do an http request but since there is an cloud_firestore package (dart/Flutter) I thought that would be the best way to go, guessing it would handle the authentication for me.

The endpoint is just an express app:

```
const app = express();
app.post('/message', async function (req:any, res: any) {
   ...
   other code
   ...
}
```

In my Flutter app I do:

```
final HttpsCallable addMessage = new CloudFunctions(region: "us-central1")
      .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'api');
  addMessage.call();
```

This will return a NOT_FOUND error, probably because I have to pass in the path for ExpressJS.
But I have not a clue about how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase callable functions client library does not work with arbitrary HTTP endpoints. It's meant to work only with callable functions that you write according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

If you have a standard HTTP endpoint, just use a regular HTTP client library for that.

If you want to pass Firebase Auth credentials along with the request, there are some examples of that in the [Firebase Admin SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). (You use the Admin SDK to verify the credentials passed from the client app.)

Comment: Thank you, I was kind of expecting this answer. I will use a http library and I think I can handle the auth because I was also able to call it with Postman. Just setting the auth headers should work right..?

Comment: It's up to you to determine how to pass the user's credentials.  The client and server will have to agree on where to find them.  Just passing them is not enough to implement any sort of security - your backend will also have to verify them and determine what to do.

Comment: Yes of course. I made some middle ware for my ExpressJS api that checks for the token in the headers. That was already working so that's why I made it sound so obvious, sry